# Programming paradigms

Tags: programming, documentation

I need a comparison table showing the solution of the same problem with different paradigms like function based, rule based, procedural etc. I remember seeing such a comparison in the Wolfram documentation, but can't find it now. Could you help?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/183/)?

Comment: Also this: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/1847/